# Third Party OAuth sign-up and login integration for mobile app

Tags: android, ios, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am new to using third parties to provide login/sign up for an app I am building. I am just trying to get the email and name of the users via them logging in via Google, Facebook, or LinkedIn. I am also storing which one they signed up with just for the database's sake. I have come to a cross road. Right now the server is run using ruby, but there is an Android and iOS (Swift) app. I am wondering if I need to integrate all the third party SDKs or if I can just use a webview with OmniAuth for Ruby or would that not work? Any hints or direction on this would be appreciated. I am really lost and when I google anything I just get one provider and not a general answer.

Answer (score 2):

Google and Facebook Login SDKs are very easy to implement and would give a richer experience on App compared to WebView also error handling is better after Facebook introduced the edit permissions in their latest update.

Linkedin Mobile SDK on the other hand needs Official Linkedin App to be installed in device. link: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth So it will make user download a 16Mb linkedin app then signin  before it can return back to your app. Also there is no iOS SDK for Linkedin yet

If Linkedin in not a necessity go for G+ and FB SDKs else use OmniAuth
PS: i have no experience with OmniAuth

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful information, especially on linkedin.